# Using in vs exists on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I know there are very similar questions about this topic. The thing is that every example I've seen points to EXISTS and IN being the same and returning the same results. I have an example of using both but I'm getting different results. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. I'm new to SQl in general.
Here are my code examples using MySQL.

First query using IN

```
 select lastname, firstname
 from employees
 where officecode in (select officecode from offices where country = 'USA');
```

The result:

[image]

Second query using EXISTS:

```
select lastname, firstname
from employees
 where exists (select officecode from offices where country = 'USA');
```

Result:

[image]

Obviously the queries are not equivalent as I'm getting different results. Am I using IN and EXISTS the wrong way?

Comment: Yes, because every row in employees will be matched in the 2nd query because the subquery will always return something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two queries are very different.  The first query is:

```
select e.lastname, e.firstname
from employees e
where e.officecode in (select o.officecode from offices o where o.country = 'USA');
```

(Note that I qualified all the column names.)

This gets employees where the corresponding office is in the USA.

This query is quite different:

```
select e.lastname, e.firstname
from employees e
where exists (select o.officecode from offices o where o.country = 'USA');
```

It is an all-or-nothing query.  It returns all employees if *any* office is in the USA.  It returns nothing otherwise.

To be equivalent to the first query, you need a *correlation* clause.  This connects the inner query to the outer query:

```
select e.lastname, e.firstname
from employees e
where exists (select 1   
              from offices o
              where  o.officecode = e.officecode and o.country = 'USA'
             );
```

With this change, the two queries should produce identical results.

Answer (score 2):

`Exists` checks for the condition to be true.

So in the second query it will run the first part of the query whenever `exists` condition is true in the inner query. Exists will check if the inner query returns one or more than one row. In your case it will be true and hence the outer query will be like `select lastname, firstname from employees;`

But in the first case it will check the condition where all the `officecode` are found in the subquery and matches the `officecode` in the outer query and will return the ones which has country `USA`

Answer (score 2):

For them to return the same results, you need a where clause for your exist statement to relate it to your outer query...  `from employees e where exists (select o.officecode from offices o where o.country = 'USA' and o.officecode = e.officecode)`. The return of each is different as well. `EXISTS` returns a `BOOLEAN`.

Answer (score 0):

Left join and null check is faster.

```
Select * from t1 
Left join t2 on(t1.=t2)
Where t2.id is null
```

Comment: How is this related to what OP asked?